# FizzBuzz in Objective-C

Tags: beginner, objective-c, fizzbuzz

In my quest for learning Objective-C, I have created the common FizzBuzz code in it.  This is due to [a suggestion/challenge](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/16550340#16550340) from [@nhgrif](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/36366/nhgrif) to re-implement [anything he does in Swift](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/56805/27623) in Objective-C.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; ++i)
        {
            if (i % 15 == 0) NSLog(@"FizzBuzz");
            else if (i % 3 == 0) NSLog(@"Fizz");
            else if (i % 5 == 0) NSLog(@"Buzz");
            else NSLog(@"%d", i);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd probably code the logic inside the loop this way:

```
if (i % fizz_divisor == 0) {        
    if (i % buzz_divisor == 0) {
        NSLog(@"FizzBuzz");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Fizz");
    }
} else if (i % buzz_divisor == 0) { 
    NSLog(@"Buzz");
} else {
    NSLog(@"%d", i);
}
```

This invokes the `%` operator at most two times, rather than possibly three times.
Of course now you have to define the constants `fizz_divisor` and `buzz_divisor`,
but it is easier to make the program continue to work correctly if you later decide
that the divisors should be something other than 3 and 5.
It's also a pattern that's relatively easily extended if you want to
implement a third divisor (e.g. to play "Fizz Buzz Ding").

Comment: I like this. It does sacrifice some readability for performance, but I really like that you only have to call the mod operator 3 times instead of the four times in my answer.

Comment: I only had to _write_ it three times. It gets called twice. We could modify this code a little to write the mod operator only two times, but that might not be good for readability and it would do nothing for performance.

Comment: Yup. You're right @DavidK. I misspoke.

Comment: It was a good point, though. The number of expressions we have to _write_ can matter too.

Comment: @nhgrif: Yes, that's how to write just two `%` operations. It requires you to make a mental connection between the logical variables used inside the `if` and the code where those variables are defined, but if the `if` conditions were much more complicated I would do that.

Answer (score 9):

I don't like that you've implemented logic in `Main`. Move the logic into a `FizzBuzz` method and call *that* from Main. (Even though it seems really silly for such a simple program, it's not best practice to have it there.)

I'm also not a fan of hard coding `15` as the "FizzBuzz" case. What if we decide that Fizz should be 2 and Buzz should be 5? Now 15 as your first case makes no sense and Mr. Maintainer has to figure out *why* 15 is a case at all. It's easier to understand and maintain `if (i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0) {`.

This might be clearer if you consider 15,3, & 5 for what they really are. They're magic numbers and as such should be stored as constants. I don't know Obj-C, so I'll provide a pseudo code example of how I think it should be done.

```
const int fizz = 3
const int buzz = 5

if (value % fizz == 0 && value % buzz == 0) {
    Print("FizzBuzz")
} else if (value % fizz == 0) {
    Print("Fizz")
} else if (value % buzz == 0) {
    Print("Buzz")
} else {
    Print(value)
}
```

This allows us to easily update the conditions.

Or alternatively (thanks to Nhgrif and David K)

```
int fizzbuzz = lcm(fizz,buzz);
for (value = 1; value <= 100; value++) { 
    if (value % fizzbuzz == 0) {
        Print("FizzBuzz")
    } 
    //etc.
}
```

Where `lcm()` is some function that returns the lowest common multiple. At that point we may be overthinking the problem, but it does result in a robust solution.

Comment: I think the reason people use 15 is because of the ugliness of having that very line.  If you need to update the FizzBuzz case, simply multiply the new numbers together and update it.

Comment: Yes @Jamal. You're right, and it is tempting, but I stand by my opinion. Think of it this way, if this were actual production code, we could call 3,5, & 15 magic numbers and recommend they be constants. Would we want to manually update 3 constants, or 2?

Comment: Either one could work, but I guess that really also depends on the language.  I never liked having to repeat the variable anyway, but that's just me.

Comment: `value % (fizz * buzz) == 0`?

Comment: Even better @nhgrif!!

Comment: Technically, if you want to be sure it works for different values of `fizz` and `buzz`, better write `if (value % lcm(fizz, buzz) == 0)` where `lcm` is a function that returns the least common multiple of its arguments.

Comment: Forgive my math rustiness, if the LCM of two numbers ever anything less than multiplying the two numbers?  If so, can you give an example?

Comment: @nhgrif `4 * 12 == 48`, but `lcm(4,12)==4`

Comment: Okay, thanks.  That's a good point.  And in which case, we'd want to calculate and set the `lcm` before the loop rather than calculate this unchanging value on each iteration of the loop.

Comment: And at this point, we're all overthinking FizzBuzz and have failed the interview question. =;)-

Comment: The LCM of 12 and 15 is 60, for example. It is true, however, that the LCM of two _prime_ numbers (such as 3 and 5) will always be their product, so as long as you stick to prime numbers (which is in the spirit of FizzBuzz, after all) then my "improvement" is unnecessary.

Comment: Just as in C, stuff you define at file scope is visible to the other files in the project.  I suggest making your constants `static` to hide them from the linker and any other source files.  (I realize there is probably only one file in this project, but the best habit is to hide everything that doesn't need to be visible.

Comment: @GraniteRobert, I clearly stated that I don't know ObjC and that this is pseudocode.

Comment: @ckuhn203: I understand; I'm just pointing out that normal C behavior applies in Objective-C.  I'd have made the same suggestion if this was C (or C++). You didn't say you don't know C.  :-)

Answer (score 8):

**You have no curly braces!**

You should be sure to include curly braces.  For one, it prevents mistakes when you want to go back and add some logic into one of these `if` statements in the future, and for two, since we're talking about Objective-C and you're almost certainly using Xcode, it makes the code collapsable.

---

I know, for some reason, that `main` drops its opening curly brace to the next line.  I don't know why, and usually, I could care less because honestly, we spend almost no time in `main` when developing iOS/OSX projects, however... by default the `@autoreleasepool` leaves its opening brace on the same line, and the autocomplete on `for` statements do this as well.

It's a style thing, yes, but in Objective-C, we prefer the opening brace on the same line.  *And there's actually a good reason for this...*  If you notice in the left-hand margin of your code, just to the right of the line numbers, there are differing shades of gray.  Clicking these shades of gray collapses different sections of your code.

Compare the difference of collapsing a `for` loop with the brace on the same line versus the brace on it's own line.  To me, the latter looks silly and it takes up an extra line!

So all in all this looks a bit better:

```
int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; ++i) {
            if (i % 15 == 0) {
                NSLog(@"FizzBuzz");
            } else if (i % 3 == 0) {
                NSLog(@"Fizz");
            } else if (i % 5 == 0) { 
                NSLog(@"Buzz");
            } else {
                NSLog(@"%d", i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good points about the collapsible code using braces, that's something I didn't think of when eliminating them.

Answer (score 2):

I'm no Objective-C expert, but it seems to me that since you are using neither `argc` nor `argv` that you could use `int main(void)`.

Also, you could alternatively store the results of `(i % 3 == 0)` and `(i % 5 == 0)` and use those within the `if` statement.

It also seems that a `return 0` might be needed at the end of `main()`.

Comment: In comment to your last point, I assumed that Objective-C inherited and abided by the C specification, specifically in C99 & C11 §5.1.2.2(3):
"...reaching the `}` that terminates the `main()` function returns a value of 0."

Comment: @syb0rg: You might well be right. Lacking a standard specification for Objective-C is a [well-known problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906767/objective-c-standards-document).

Comment: If we're going to go about removing bits of `main` that were auto-generated, we could remove the `@autoreleasepool` too, since there's no objects in the code.

Answer (score 1):

If we want to sacrifice readability in favor of performance, we might like something like this:

```
const int kFizz = 3;
const int kBuzz = 5;

for (int i = 1; i <= 100; ++i) {
    NSLog(@"%@",
        i % kFizz ? (i % kBuzz ? @"FizzBuzz" : @"Fizz") :
                    (i % kBuzz ? @"Buzz"     : @(i))
    );
}
```

The key to understanding this solution is that the `%@` placeholder calls the `description` method on whatever argument it is sent.  With `NSString`, the `description` is exactly what you'd expect.  The tricky part here is `@(i)`.  The `@(i)` is modern Objective-C syntax which instantiates an `NSNumber` object, and calling the `description` method on an `NSNumber` object is almost equivalent to using the `%i` string format placeholder for an integer.

Comment: I usually align the two branches of a `?:` operator to start in the same column when they occur on separate lines. That might improve readability here.

Comment: @DavidK Can you edit to show me how you mean?  I typically don't nest ternary operators, and was trying to indent etc. to make it most readable but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Done. I also added a line of text because SO didn't believe that my other edits added up to 6 characters, and it wouldn't let me submit them without adding something else.

Comment: This is Code *Review* not Code *Golf*.

Comment: I was under the understanding that efficiency is a perfectly reviewable topic.  This is the most efficient method.  It doesn't sacrifice readability for the sake of fewer characters--only for better performance.