# FizzBuzz in Swift 2

Tags: swift, fizzbuzz

I saw this question: 
[Is this FizzBuzz Swift-y?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/56805/is-this-fizzbuzz-swift-y) and I couldn't resist the temptation to attempt a Swift2 implementation:

```
for i in 1...100 {
    switch i {
    case _ where i % 15 == 0: print("FizzBuzz")
    case _ where i %  3 == 0: print("Fizz")
    case _ where i %  5 == 0: print("Buzz")
    default                 : print(String(i))
    }
}
```

Is this swift-y and clear enough? Can you suggest any improvement?

Comment: You could make it a function where you pass "Fizz", "Buzz" and the numbers as parameters to be more re-usable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I don't know sqat about [swift](/questions/tagged/swift)*

It's clear and aesthetically pleasing.

But, I think in any language, this is a sign of abusing the `switch` construct:

> ```
> case _ where ...
> case _ where ...
> case _ where ...
> default:
> ```

That is, using a bunch of useless "case _ where" is a sign that probably should replace with natural and good old fashioned if-else-if-else.

Another thing, I see that you nicely aligned the `:` in all four lines.
Sometimes that looks pretty.
But such practice usually bites you back later when you need to modify the code.
Later when adding one more case/if, instead of focusing on the new case/if alone, if it would place a new `:` out of order with the others, then you would be compelled to edit all the other lines too.

Answer (score 9):

I would have started by looking over more than just the question in the linked question.  You should have looked at the answers.

First of all, while the added `where` clause option in `switch` statements is a nice addition to the language, it doesn't make anything better here.

Moreover, we're failing on the single-responsibility-principle by not extracting out a method which takes an `Int` and returns a `String` and then simply looping over calls to this function.

So, the answer to this question is effectively going to be an a rewrite of the accepted answer of the linked question:

```
func fizzBuzzify(value: Int) -> String {
    switch (value % 3, value % 5) {
    case (0,0): return "FizzBuzz"
    case (0,_): return "Fizz"
    case (_,0): return "Buzz"
    default: return String(value)
    }
}

func fizzBuzz(startingValue: Int = 1, endingValue: Int = 100) {
    for i in startingValue...endingValue {
        print(fizzBuzzify(i))
    }
}
```

Then you get it all done in a single line:

```
fizzBuzz()
```

Comment: What about replacing the `startingValue`/`endingValue`  pair with a single `range: Range<Int>` argument? It would make the `fizzBuzz` function as simple as`range.forEach(fizzBuzzify)`.

Answer (score 0):

I personally like nhgrif's answer. If you want to take it to the next level you could possibly define your FizzBuzz solution as a `SequenceType` (Swift 2.2) `Sequence` (Swift 3.0)

```
struct FizzBuzzSequence: Sequence {
  func makeIterator() -> AnyIterator<String> {
    var _first = 0
    func fizzBuzzify(value: Int) -> String {
        switch (value % 3, value % 5) {
        case (0,0): return "FizzBuzz"
        case (0,_): return "Fizz"
        case (_,0): return "Buzz"
        default: return String(value)
        }
    }    
    return AnyIterator<String> {
      _first += 1
      return fizzBuzzify(value: _first)
    }
  }
}

var fizzBuzzIterator = FizzBuzzSequence().lazy.makeIterator()
for _ in 0..<200 {
  if let val = fizzBuzzIterator.next(){
    print(val)
  }
}
```

Doing so would provide your FizzBuzz sequence with map, reduce and filter functionality on top of many other good stuff for free.